# Up two war in to Nexus with maven deploy

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus

I have a project with two wars, the back-end and the front-end and I have to deploy with maven to a Nexus repository, I did it with the back-end but how can I do that with the front-end?

Thanks a lot to everyone.